# Java Swing - ImageIcon in Jtable within a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, render, jscrollpane

I have a JTable inside a JScrollPane. In one of the columns in the JTable, I have ImageIcons being displayed. Everything works fine, however, I have that in windows XP, when you scroll the rendering messes up and images become distorted.

This only happens when you scroll.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKqYT.png

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: To clarify: does it work properly on some other operating systems? If so, which ones?

Comment: Yep it works properly on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an adjustment listener to your scroll bar and repaint the table on ajustment value changed events.

```
scrollBar=new JScrollPane(table);
scrollBar.getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(this);

public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
    table.repaint();

    }
```

Comment: This worked. Except I had to repaint the table, not the scroll bar :)

Comment: I have changed the code.Please confirm if this is what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Images display fine on XP. Try out the example from [UIManager Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/26/text-utilities/). Click on "By Value Type" and then select "Icons" from the combo box.